# Use API instead of Proxy in wso2 ei message broker

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

Is it possible use api instead of proxy in communication between message broker and ei on wso2?
I've studied about connection message broker and enterprise integrator, but in all documents implementation was with proxy service. So, because of authentication and some topics related to api in wso2 I need to implement api instead of proxy service. How I can implement and connect to message broker on enterprise integrator with api?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to send message from an EI API to the message broker but not consume them.

Most basic sending setup:

```
 <endpoint>
     <address uri="jms:/<queueName>?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=myQueueConnectionFactory&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
  </endpoint>
```

For consuming you will need a proxy.

I don't know your exact use case of course but usually in these kinds of situations the API will forward to a queue and the mediation will be handled by a proxy afterwards.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/JMS+Support